# angular-cli build gives error: leaflet.browser.print "is not a module"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet, angular-cli

I have an Angular 4.1.1 app that is successfully pulling in leaflet.js to provide maps and map layers etc.  I am trying to add a leaflet plugin called [browserPrint](https://github.com/Igor-Vladyka/leaflet.browser.print)

I import Leaflet into a Component like this:

```
import * as L from "leaflet";
import * as browserPrint from "../../../../assets/scripts/leaflet.browser.print.min";
```

The import statement for Leaflet works great and I can create and display a map.

The error occurs when I try and add the second line for **browserPrint**.

The angular-cli build throws an error:

> ERROR in
>   /src/app/services/driverLists/driver-lists-map/driverLists.map.component.ts
>   (8,31): File '/src/assets/scripts/leaflet.browser.print.min.js' is not
>   a module.

What I have tried:

1. I added **declare var browserPrint: any;** to the typings.d.ts
2. I tried switching the import to:

   **import "../../../../assets/scripts/leaflet.browser.print.min";**

   but that just threw tons of errors and broke the maps all together
3. I tried switching the import to:

   **import * as BrowserPrint from "../../../../assets/scripts/leaflet.browser.print";**

   but the error changes to ***Cannot find module leaflet.browser.print***
4. I have also tried changing the file paths to use the files from the leaflet.browser.print node modules folder.  But the same errors are generated.

### QUESTION

Can someone help me figure out how to add the leaflet browser print plugin to a leaflet map inside an Angular4+ app?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible that the minified version you have of that script isn't actually exporting any object? Unlikely but I figured I'd ask.

Comment: Also, just a style thing, but why do you have a component in your services folder? :/

Comment: ha, services describe a part of the application, the client provides "services" of on-site installations, and they are stuck on the terminology for describing what they do for their own clients.

Comment: whoopsies. My bad. I shouldn't have assumed, lol. anyway, back to my first question

Comment: so the files do not export anything, they are meant to augment the existing leaflet.js functions

Comment: Yeah. So the reason it's failing is because it doesn't export anything. So you can't import them.

Comment: I guess I am wondering what my options are, how can I add these plugins to my angular app for use with the existing leaflet.js map

Comment: Ok, so, try this. I think you want to include the file in the "scripts" array in your angular-cli.json. That should wrap it up in your webpack output, and you won't need to actually import it. Does that work for you?

Comment: Added an official answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I saw in the documentation for [ngx-leaflet](https://github.com/bluehalo/ngx-leaflet-tutorial-plugins/tree/master/Leaflet.BrowserPrint) that we should create a ./src/typings.d.ts file and add the below code.

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
declare module 'leaflet' {
  namespace control {
    function browserPrint(options?: any): Control.BrowserPrint;
  }
  namespace Control {
    interface BrowserPrint {
      addTo(map: L.Map): any;
    }
  }
}
```

It worked for me this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to include the file in the "scripts" array in your angular-cli.json. That should wrap it up in your webpack output, and you won't need to actually import it (as you've said above, that particular file doesn't export anything, so you can't import it anyway).

Documentation here:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts

Comment: already tried that, the browserPrint that should be accessible prevents building via the cli

Comment: well lets try to fix this issue then because i believe this is the correct way to solve your problem, it's just not working. I feel like i've run into the same issue before (angular.cli scripts couldn't be found by webpack while building). I'll brainstorm

Comment: this link is an example I am trying to follow https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-tutorial-plugins/tree/master/Leaflet.BrowserPrint